# Angle sum at center of a skewed quadrilateral

Tags: computational-geometry

The center of a *discrete* quadrilateral on a positive, flat or negative curved surface should make angles sum at center point 2  less than, equal to or more than $360^{\circ}$ respectively, making them (elliptic , flat, saddle ) points.

To test this hypothesis for the latter case a big ( not a differential but discrete length diagonal segments /sides ) skew quadrilateral of negatively curved pseudosphere is calculated from its ode with polar interval $45^{\circ}$ and coordinates of $(1,2,3,4,5)$ are in Table . Points $(1,5) $ are on the cuspidal equator.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a = 1.; sii = Pi/2.; phi = -Pi/2; ri = 1; smax = 1.7;
PSnet = {SI'[s] == Sin[PH[s]]/a, SI[0] == sii, 
   PH'[s] == -Sin[SI[s]]/a, PH[0] == phi, 
   R'[s]/Cos[SI[s]] == Sin[PH[s]], Z'[s] == Cos[PH[s]] Cos[SI[s]], 
   TH'[s] == Sin[SI[s]]/R[s], R[0] == ri, Z[0] == 0, TH[0] == 0.};
NDSolve[PSnet, {SI, PH, R, TH, Z}, {s, 0, smax}];
{si[t_], ph[t_], r[t_], th[t_], 
   z[t_]} = {SI[t], PH[t], R[t], TH[t], Z[t]} /. First[%];
m1 = ParametricPlot[{z[s], r[s]}, {s, .0, smax}, 
  PlotLabel -> TRACTRIX, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}]
" Finding angle sum at Rhombus center > 2 Pi"
sor1 = ParametricPlot3D[{r[s] Cos[th[s] + v], r[s] Sin[th[s] + v], 
    z[s]}, {s, .0, smax}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLabel -> CANOPY, 
   PlotStyle -> White];
fila1 = ParametricPlot3D[{r[s] Cos[th[s]], r[s] Sin[th[s]], 
    z[s]}, {s, .0, smax}, PlotLabel -> 3 _D Projn, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
gam = Pi/4;
fila2 = ParametricPlot3D[{r[s] Cos[th[s] - 2 gam], 
    r[s] Sin[th[s] - 2 gam], z[s]}, {s, .0, smax}, 
   PlotLabel -> 3 _D Projn,
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}];
fila3 = ParametricPlot3D[{r[s] Cos[th[s]], -r[s] Sin[th[s]], 
    z[s]}, {s, .0, smax}, PlotLabel -> 3 _D Projn, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
gam = Pi/4;
fila4 = ParametricPlot3D[{r[s] Cos[th[s] - 2 gam], -r[s] Sin[
      th[s] - 2 gam], z[s]}, {s, .0, smax}, PlotLabel -> 3 _D Projn,
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}];
s1 = Show[{sor1, fila1, fila2, fila3, fila4}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, PlotLabel -> "LINES_ PseudoSphere"]
i = 1; $ = ",";
dth = Pi/4; ds = dth*1; r[s_] = Sech[th[s]];
Table[{i++, $, r[s], $, th[s], $, 
   z[s], $ r[s] Cos[th[s]], $, +r[s] Sin[th[s]], $, z[s], $, 
   si[s]}, {s, 0., smax, ds}] // TableForm
```

[image]

Please help in finding the non-coplanar four angles sum at point 2 having found the five  vertices of the quadrilateral in order to find the sum $> 2 \pi .$

My first trial using cross-products in the four regions at point 2 was initially not successful. Is there a theorem or an easier way to compute?

Thanks for your attention; please comment if any part of the problem is not clear.

Comment: Have you tried `VectorAngle`?

Comment: Did you use the actual segments between point 2 and points 1-5 (excluding 2)? Or did you use the tangents to the surface at point 2? It's the latter that should be used.

Comment: Thanks. Shall go through to check if made any errors and post here again.